# How can I get the random nextMove state every turn?

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code like this. But I don't know how to return the different move with my nextMove() func every time I call them in my main program. I'm newbie, pls help.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, str_name):
        self.str = str_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.str

    def nextMove(self, state):
        result = [(1,1),(2,2)]
        return result
```

Comment: What are the possibilities for moves ?

Comment: It has range from 0 to 7 (English draughts table). I already tried to use random library, create 4 variables in that class but it returned an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from random import randint

class Player:
    def __init__(self, str_name):
        self.str = str_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.str

    def nextMove(self, state):
        result = [(randint(0,8),randint(0,8)) for _ in range(2)]
        return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Player('Simba')
    for i in range(5):
        print(player.nextMove('Safari'))

# [(10, 2), (2, 4)]
# [(4, 0), (10, 0)]
# [(3, 0), (4, 4)]
# [(8, 4), (2, 3)]
# [(4, 4), (2, 1)]
```

It is not very clear how the `nextMove` method should be defined. The `state` parameter is not used anywhere in the method definition. Therefore, I set it to "Safari" in my example.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Can I create variables in this class and put it into the result . I tried but it failed

Comment: @congbang10h Please provide some code and error tracebacks, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I post another detail topic, you can move that and see my entire program. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464930/how-to-utilize-minimax-algorithm-in-english-checkers-game). 
Thanks for your help @TrakJohnson